# Chinese Beliefs about God and the physical world

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, chinese-philosophy

I'm not sure if this question ought to be here, but I hope someone can help me out anyway... What is the major religious belief in China nowadays? Traditional buddhism taught by Gautama Buddha (i.e. the dharma) or Taoism, folk religion?? What is their basic beliefs about God and the physical world? 
Basically what I want to know is what is most Chinese people's beliefs about God now?

Comment: Are you asking what Chinese people believe now or what Chinese philosophy has said about God in different traditions?

Comment: Hello. What I meant to ask was what do most Chinese people believe now. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about contemporary beliefs of regular Chinese people rather than something specific to Chinese philosophy.

Comment: Oh...I see. So may I know where to place it?

Comment: I don't think there is a religion.se ... and I didn't see say an anthropology one either.

Comment: There is a comparative religion Area51 proposal. Probably worth following if you think a stack exchange for this kind of question is worth while. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58788/comparative-religion

Answer (score -1):

On ["The Tao of Zen"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tao_of_Zen) wiki writes:

> The work argues that what we recognize as traditional Chinese
>   Ch'an/Japanese Zen Buddhism is in fact almost entirely grounded in
>   Chinese Taoist philosophy, though this fact is well shrouded by the
>   persistence of Mahayana Buddhist institutional trappings. ...
>
> The story unfolds in China as Buddhism appears on the scene and is
>   accepted by the Chinese population as a "simplified version of Taoism"
>   that the Western barbarians (subcontinent Indians and Central Asians,
>   e.g. Tibetans, et al.) could understand. They shared many
>   philosophical similarities that made Chinese acclimation to Buddhism
>   much easier – but the more dogmatic ways in which Buddhism was
>   practiced helped it to get the fast track on becoming the predominant
>   religion in China.

And on ["Tao"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao) wiki writes:

> The concept of Tao was shared with Confucianism, Chán and Zen Buddhism
>   and more broadly throughout East Asian philosophy and religion in
>   general. Within these contexts Tao signifies the primordial essence or
>   fundamental nature of the universe. In the foundational text of
>   Taoism, the Tao Te Ching, Laozi explains that Tao is not a 'name' for
>   a 'thing' but the underlying natural order of the universe whose
>   ultimate essence is difficult to circumscribe.

The Tao sounds like a fairly reasonable 'God' concept, loosely speaking.  Obviously it doesn't have the triple nature of The Trinity.

I can't answer on religion on China nowadays.  As far as I am aware religion was suppressed during the [Cultural Revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_Revolution).  ***Postscript***: Virmaior comments that "Religion [in China is] alive and well in many forms of Buddhism, animism, Confucianism, and Christianity."

Comment: Unfortunately, at least the last part of your information is deeply mistaken. Religion does not merely "linger" in the form of Chan (Zen) and Taoism. It's alive and well in many forms of Buddhism, animism, Confucianism, and Christianity. The cultural revolution was unable to wipe out the religious sentiments of Chinese people and ended long ago...

Comment: @virmaior - thanks for the clarification. I edited my post.